# text-to-speech c++ mac/windows

Tags: text-to-speech

I believe I have asked a similar question before, but how could I get text-to-speech capabilities in my program. I have just started programming so not too complicated please!
No links to other sites either please, as I will not understand them. Also can it preferably be for windows and mac, but if you cannot make it universal, my preference would be for mac.
Thanks
Update:
I would like to know exactly what code to include to be able to add the text-to-speech.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I can help you regarding Mac. There is a "Speech Synthesis Manager" API that you can use from Mac OS, and - yes - I'll give you a link, since programming DOES require understanding links.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Speech_Synthesis_Manager/Reference/reference.html

But, here are you also a short (working) example:

```
void SpeechDoneProc (SpeechChannel chan, long refCon)
{
    DisposeSpeechChannel(chan);
}

void SpeakThisText(const void *text, long size)
{
    SpeechChannel chan;

    NewSpeechChannel (NULL, &chan);
    SetSpeechInfo(chan, soSpeechDoneCallBack, (void*)&SpeechDoneProc); // we install a callback to dispose the channel when ready
    SpeakText (chan, text, size);
}
```

Good luck!

EDIT>>
There is another function that can be used, if you get confused of what encoding should the text be passed - `SpeakCFString(...)`.

But those are Carbon-based. There is something newer (although it is the same under the hood), and it is wrapped in `NSSpeechSynthesizer` class.

And, finally, there is another link which is more useful:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/UsingSpeech/UsingSpeech.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH4-SW2

Answer (score -1):

We have a TTS SDK for Mac an Windows, with a C/C++ API.
Check http://www.acapela-for-developers.com

Jean-Michel Reghem
Developer Solutions Product Manager
Acapela Group

Comment: Consider expanding your answer with some excerpt from the referenced page. See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for details why bare links are not welcome.

Comment: I reverted this back ti the original version because the site rules encourage disclosing affiliation with software recommendations.